# Enabling Z-ray panel in Zend server doesn't work

Tags: zend-server

I use Zend server 2019 locally and I have enabled the Z-ray exactly according this info https://help.zend.com/zend/current/content/enabling_disabling_z-ray.htm

So both options under the Enable section are checked, server restarted, but still there is no panel in my browser, there is even no requests to z-ray.

Is there anyone to help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was, that I was running Zend server in Docker, and there were for some reason 3 different Zend containers. After I removed them and only one is now there, the Z-ray started to work and everything is fine.